# Lucene Search for documents that have a particular field?

Tags: search, lucene.net

Lucene.Net -
Is there a way to query for documents that contain a particular field.

Lets say some of my documents have a field 'foo' and some do not.

I want to find all documents that have the field 'foo' - regardless of what the value of foo is.

How do I do this?  Is it some sort of TermQuery?

Comment: Try checking out one of the tutorials here: http://ifdefined.com/blog/post/Full-Text-Search-in-ASPNET-using-LuceneNET.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try foo:[* TO *]
should work for all non-null values of field 'foo'

Comment: Does an empty string count as a "null" value? I didn't know Lucene supported null-valued fields.