# Find all Lucene documents having a certain field

Tags: lucene

I want to find all documents in the index that have a certain field, regardless of the field's value. If at all possible using the query language, not the API.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the type of data stored in your field, you can try a range query. Per example, if your field contain string data, a query like `field:[a* TO z*]` would return all documents where there is a string value in that field.

Comment: This should work. It would be slightly more complex in case the field has values starting with numbers or capital letters. Should be easy to do with an OR query.

Comment: Good point! But if it starts with a capital, a range starting with a* should catch it because the javadoc of TermRangeQuery states that it uses String.compareTo to determine if a string is part of the range.

Comment: This looks good. Not sure about catching records starting with numbers, but this is a good start. Thanks!

Comment: The lexicographic order of strings defines numbers before letters so a range [0* TO z*] would catch all values starting by both letters and numbers. And capital letters appears before lower-case (in contrary to what I have said in my previous comment). Don't forget to check how your values are indexed: they may be all lower-cased!

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686033/lucene-search-for-documents-that-have-a-particular-field/2726574#2726574 field:[* TO *] will also work, however you may have to enable `SetAllowLeadingWildcard` on the `QueryParser`.

Answer (score 3):

I've done some experimenting, and it seems the simplest way to achieve this is to create a `QueryParser` and call `SetAllowLeadingWildcard( true )` and search for `field:*` like so:

```
var qp = new QueryParser( Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, field, analyzer );
qp.SetAllowLeadingWildcard( true );
var query = qp.Parse( "*" ) );
```

*(Note I am setting the default field of the `QueryParser` to `field` in its constructor, hence the search for just `"*"` in `Parse()`).*

I cannot vouch for how efficient this method is over other methods, but being the simplest method I can find, I would expect it to be at least as efficient as `field:[* TO *]`, and it avoids having to do hackish things like `field:[0* TO z*]`, which may not account for all possible values, such as values starting with non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is using a ConstantScoreQuery with a FieldValueFilter

```
new ConstantScoreQuery(new FieldValueFilter("field"))
```