# Lucene get documents containing specific field name

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

I am using lucene in my project and I got to one issue, that I need to find documents which contain fields with specific name. I was only able to find solutions where you creating search term containing pairs name,value like this:

```
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directoryReader);
TermQuery query = new TermQuery(new Term("name", "value"));
TopDocs topdocs = searcher.query(query, numberToReturn);
```

but as I stated, I need to find documents only by provided name of field and obtain access to value of field specified by name in selected documents.

Although I am working with Lucene.NET I will be thankfull for solution in any language.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710089/find-all-lucene-documents-having-a-certain-field) and little change made it:

```
 var queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "content", analyzer);
 queryParser.AllowLeadingWildcard = true;
 var query = queryParser.Parse( "*" );
```