# Lucene query with filter "without property"

Tags: lucene, alfresco, alfresco-share

I need to write lucene query/filter to get objects without specific property. 
I tried with ... ISNULL:"cm:param_name" but id didn't work.

Edit: I have added new property in aspect but objects that haven't been updated yet don't have it amongst their listed properties (checked with node browser).

Answer (score 1):

With a query like "cm:*", you should only receive documents that have the field "cm" plus content. Note that you have to allow leading wildcard queries by the query parser with **setAllowLeadingWildcard**(true).

Also check out this post, which deals with a reversed version of your problem:
[Find all Lucene documents having a certain field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710089/find-all-lucene-documents-having-a-certain-field)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please be more clear as to what "without property" means ? Do you mean that you do not want to specify the field like so "field:value" and instead set the filter to "value" ?

EDIT

Are you generating these field names dynamically or is this the only field name that can have it's value missing ? If there is only one field that may or may not appear in your document then you could just populate it with a default value when it's missing and then search for that . Otherwise, you could try a negated rangequery like so : NOT foo:[* TO *] . This should match all documents without a value in the foo field. For performance purposes , in the second case the field should be indexed as a string field (not analyzed).

Comment: I couldn't follow you explanation. It must be same to you with my question. :D Use comments on question next time for this. I want all objects that doesn't have this property (yet). I have added new property in aspect but objects that haven't been updated yet don't have it amongst their listed properties (checked with node browser). I'll add this explanation to the question.

Comment: so you want all documents without the cm field, or just all documents that do not have the cm field set to "param_name" . If the second case is what you want you can just try adding a NOT or a - in front of your clause like so : "NOT cm:param_name" or "-cm:param_name" . If you are building the query yourself that would be a boolean query with a MUST_NOT modifier

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this done with .. AND NOT (@namespace\:property:"")

Answer (score 0):

In Java and Lucene 3.6.2 the "FieldValueFilter" with activated negation can be used: (which was not the question)

```java
import org.apache.lucene.search.FieldValueFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.MatchAllDocsQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;

final IndexSearcher indexSearcher = getIndexSearcher() <- whereever that comes from
final TopDocs topdocs = indexSearcher.search(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), new FieldValueFilter("cm", true), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: this is java solution, when I needed this I needed plain lucene query

Comment: ouch .. sorry, i found this after asking google for "lucene property filter". I figured out this solution afterwards .. Should i delete my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISUNSET and/or ISNULL for this scenario.

```
ISUNSET:"cm:title"
ISNULL:"cm:title"
```